# Connecting Google News

Tags: python, https

I've had been using the following piece of code to retrieve Google News:

```
def gopen(dom):
  http = httplib.HTTPSConnection('news.google.com')
  http.request("GET","/news?ned=es_%s" % dom.lower(),
                headers =
               {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; es-%s) AppleWebKit/532.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/4.0.277.0 Safari/532.8" % dom,
               "Host":'news.google.com',
               "Accept": "*/*"})
  return http.getresponse()
```

A few days ago, Google News has been revamped and it doesn't work any more (2.6/Win, 2.7/OSX and, with minimal changes, 3.6/Win). How can I fix it? I must stick to the standard libraries.

**EDIT.** The headers are:

```
[('Content-Type', 'application/binary'),
 ('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate'),
 ('Pragma', 'no-cache'),
 ('Expires', 'Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT'),
 ('Date', 'Thu, 13 Jul 2017 16:37:48 GMT'),
 ('Location', 'https://news.google.com/news/?ned=es_mx&hl=es'),
 ('Strict-Transport-Security', 'max-age=10886400'),
 ('P3P',
  'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See '
 'https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."'),
 ('Server', 'ESF'),
 ('Content-Length', '0'),
 ('X-XSS-Protection', '1; mode=block'),
 ('X-Frame-Options', 'SAMEORIGIN'),
 ('X-Content-Type-Options', 'nosniff'),
 ('Set-Cookie', 'NID=107=qwH7N2hB12zVGfFzrAC2CZZNhrnNAVLEmTvDvuSzzw6mSlta9D2RDZVP9t5gEcq_WJjZQjDSWklJ7LElSnAZnHsiF4CXOwvGDs2tjrXfP41LE-6LafdA86GO3sWYnfWs;Domain=.google.com;Path=/;Expires=Fri, '
 '12-Jan-2018 16:37:48 GMT;HttpOnly'),
 ('Alt-Svc', 'quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="39,38,37,36,35"')]
```

`read()`returns an empty string. `status` is 302. `reason` is `Found`.

Comment: What doesn't work? What is the traceback?

Comment: @roganjosh Sorry for being so vague. I edited the question to add the answer from the server, because  the code itself works. Formerly Google News used to fail with the high level methods provided by htttplib and the like. but I found this piece of code somewhere.

Comment: Actually, the problem was I missed an extra bar in the Location field. I don't know how many times I compared the old URL with the new one. Silly me!